# Symfony / Sonata Custom Query to prefill choices

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

## I want to Create a Custom search Field in the FormMapper:

What it is supposed to do: As soon, as the user starts to enter data (with a minimum of 3 characters), I want to run a query against a backend to get the choices available for the given set (that is: artists with the letters "foo" for example).

I have to admit, that I have no experience with Symfony / Sonata, and I have been struggling for 2 Days now. So what I have - and what would make sense is, to create a

```
// in Bundle/Admin/ArtistAdmin.php
        $formMapper
            ->add('artist', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
                'keys' => array(
                    array('type', 'choice',
                        array('choices' => array('callback'   => array($this, 'getArtists')))))))
```

So I setup a callback, that pings me back the input, the user did so far.

```
// in Bundle/Admin/ArtistAdmin.php
public static function getArtists($value)
{

    if (!(strlen($value) > 2)) return null;
      // get data from url for given input
      // create array
      // return array
```

But I get either a SimpleXML Error, or errors I hardly understand and I would really appreciate any help - even if only a vague pointing in a different / better direction.

Comment: I guess your are looking for [**`Shtumi Ajax autocomplete type`**](https://github.com/shtumi/ShtumiUsefulBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/ajax_autocomplete.rst)

Comment: Hey, thx, I will have a look at this. It looks promising. Will give feedback asap.